# Yii2: Adding a readonly user to PostgreSQL in a migration

Tags: postgresql, yii2, migration

Relying heavily on migrations I need to create an additional user with readonly permissions to my database `web` in a yii2 migration.

Is this possible since Yii2 does not offer to create users directly in a [Migration](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-migration)? How can this be done?

I tried this SO answer [Crate a new, read-only user in postgres](https://serverfault.com/a/757800) but did not succeed to transfer it to Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible, you have to use the `createCommand` method and use raw SQL:

```php
$user_created = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand("CREATE USER :db_username@'%' WITH PASSWORD :db_userpwd")
    ->bindValue( ':db_username', $db_username )
    ->bindValue( ':db_userpwd', $db_userpwd )
    ->execute();
```